# Google ignoring LocalBusiness sub-categories?

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, structured-data, google-rich-snippets-tool

I'm working for a review website, where we (of course) want a reference to our reviews to show up in the Local Business listing in the Google search results. The local businesses are various medical clinics.

When testing with the [Rich Result Test tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) in the search console I see there is no local business element found/listed if I use either `MedicalOrganization` or `MedicalBusiness` schemas, but if I use either `LocalBusiness` or `Hospital` there is.

I expect that for `MedicalOrganization` it is because it's not a subtype of `LocalBusiness`, but I really don't understand why `MedicalBusiness` doesn't work, as it *is* a subtype and is more precise than just using `LocalBusiness`.

Can anyone help me understand the cause of this behaviour?

---

In case it's relevant, here are a couple of examples:

1. [Clinic using the `Hospital` schema](https://www.legelisten.no/klinikker/7088-aleris-colosseum-nobel). Shows "Local Business" section in testing tool by default, but not if switching to `MedicalOrganization` or `MedicalBusiness`
2. [Clinic using `MedicalOrganization`](https://www.legelisten.no/admin/medical_practices/11967-lilleaker-kiropraktikk). Does not show "Local Business" section in testing tool by default or switching to `MedicalBusiness`, but does show it when set to `LocalBusiness` or `Hospital`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `MedicalOrganisation`, I agree with your assessment. It is not a sub-type of `LocalBusiness`, which is a requirement in Google's [specification](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/local-business). But `MedicalBusiness`, as you say, is a sub-type of `LocalBusiness` and so should work, as many other sub-types do.

My guess is it's a bug. You can report this via the "Send Feedback" link at the top of Google's specification page.

To actually solve your problem, why not use `MedicalClinic`? It validates, and seems to match your use case.

[image]

Comment: Hah, thanks for that. This feels even stranger, since MedicalClinic is a subtype of MedicalBusiness!

Comment: Just want to add that if this is a bug, it's not limited to the testing tool, as it affects the SERP too. This includes referencing our reviews in the sidebar AND stars displayed under the title of the regular search result.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm not surprised the behaviour's reflected in SERP, but it is good to see evidence that the testing tools accurately reflect what is supported in the production environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use schema's [additionalType](https://schema.org/additionalType) property in order to add more specific types from external vocabularies. By adding additionalType for MedicalBusiness under LocalBusiness your schema will look like this.

[image]

[image]

https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool#url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.legelisten.no%2Fklinikker%2F7088-aleris-colosseum-nobel

However I fail to understand why you want to do this. Why do you want the local business element to show up? Why not just use a more specific sub-type like MedicalBusiness etc.?

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the user's question. The point is that `MedicalBusiness` is ignored by the validator. If that were not the case, it would trigger a "Local businesses" section in the detected types.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nina. What @GDav is saying is correct, the issue is that MedicalBusiness is ignored, although it seems to not only be an issue with the testing tool. The search actual search results also seem to reflect this.